# 2001 Fiat punto: slave cylinder repaired brake warning light

Tags: clutch, fiat

My clutch slave cylinder was replaced today but my brake fluid warning light came on for a second on two bends.  Is this more likely an electrical fault? I will take it back to the garage nect week.

Comment: Can you explain why you think your brake warning light should be related to work on your clutch cylinder? Did you check your brake fluid level?

Comment: Sounds like a good answer instead of just a comment

Comment: I have checked the brake fluid and it seems to be topped up.

Answer (score 1):

Along the lines of what Josh is saying, a lot of cars these days have the clutch and brake master cylinders combined with a tube running from the brake to the clutch to supply it with fluid. If they didn't refill the brake fluid when they did your clutch slave, it could be causing the light to come on.